# Session is closed everytime when I'm trying to sendBinary to WebSocket server endpoint in Spring4 & Tomcat8

Tags: java, spring, websocket, tomcat8, spring-websocket

I have to webapps (A and B), both of them are B/S deployed in Tomcat8 with Spring MVC. and of course, I develop these server-side in Java7.

I'm try to send some data from A's server-side to B's server-side via WebSocket. These data is about 10k~200k and will be sent in every 2sec. I thought WebSocket maybe better than RPC/WebService in this scenario.

The problem is:
When I send text message using session.sendText, everything is fine. But When I send data using session.sendBinary, I found the session is always be closed. The spring log in B's server-side (B is the websocket server endpoint and who receives the data) is like this:

```
00:29:29,191 DEBUG OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter:160 - Opening JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter
00:29:29,191 DEBUG TransactionSynchronizationManager:193 - Bound value [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder@107c53da] for key [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@25c9b5b9] to thread [http-nio-8081-exec-1]
00:29:29,191 DEBUG TransactionSynchronizationManager:243 - Removed value [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder@107c53da] for key [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@25c9b5b9] from thread [http-nio-8081-exec-1]
00:29:29,192 DEBUG OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter:185 - Closing JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter
00:29:29,192 DEBUG EntityManagerFactoryUtils:432 - Closing JPA EntityManager
```

Every time A's trying to send the data, B's console will print these 5 line log above repeatly. I totally have no idea about where I should check...

It will be super appriciated if I could have your help.

-UPDATE-

In fact, I didn't have muche configuration for using websocket.
at B side, as the websocket server, I have the annotation on the class which I want to receive the data like this:

```
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/report")
public class ReportsWebSocketReceiver {
...
}
```

at A side, I use `ws://[IP:PORT]/[webappName]/report` to connect and send message.

That does work while connecting and sendText message, just doesn't work while sendBinary message.

BTW, It could work if I deploy the receiver class in Tomcat8 without spring, both sendText and sendBinary. So do I have to config more in web.xml or spring.xml?

Comment: post your complete configuration.

Comment: Hi Abhinay, thanks for reply. I update with more details. I found I may should config more in spring's configuration file because the reveiver (the websocket side in my system) works fine just in tomcat without spring, but I don't know what I should config...